# Python: Move files from local PC to server

Tags: python-3.x

I need to move files from my PC to a network location, however if I execute the script I get an error. If have tested this to execute on my PC to a different local folder and it works perfectly.

Here is my code which I got, and modified slightly, from https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-move-files-and-directories/ (giving credit to the author):

```
import shutil, os, glob, time

def moveAllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir):
    # Check if both the are directories
    if os.path.isdir(srcDir) and os.path.isdir(dstDir) :
        # Iterate over all the files in source directory
        for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '\*'):
            # Move each file to destination Directory
            if(os.path.getctime(filePath) != os.path.getmtime(filePath)):
                shutil.move(filePath, dstDir);
    else:
        print("srcDir & dstDir should be Directories")

sourceDir = r"C:\Folder A"
destDir =  r"\\Server\Folder B"

moveAllFilesinDir(sourceDir,destDir)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I am making use of Remote Desktop to access the server.

Errors I receive:

- FileNotFoundError: [WinError 67] The network name cannot be found.
- FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: So what error do you get? Add the full traceback -- it will help us help you.

Comment: I updated the original post, thanks. Is there a way to get around the RDP (Remote Desktop) issue?